# Query Elastic document field with and without characters

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have the following documents stored at my elasticsearch index (`my_index`):

```
{
    "name": "111666"
},
{
    "name": "111A666"
},
{
    "name": "111B666"
}
```

and I want to be able to query these documents using both the exact value of the `name` field as well as a character-trimmed version of the value.

**Examples**

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "111666"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

should return all of the (3) documents mentioned above.

On the other hand:

```
GET /my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "111a666"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

should return just one document (the one that matches exactly with the the provided value of the `name` field).

I didn't find a way to configure the settings of `my_index` in order to support such functionality (custom search/index analyzers etc..).

I should mention here that I am using ElasticSearch's Java API (`QueryBuilders`) in order to implement the above-mentioned queries, so I thought of doing it the Java-way.

**Logic**

```
1) Check if the provided query-string contains a letter
2) If yes (e.g 111A666), then search for 111A666 using a standard search analyzer
3) If not (e.g 111666), then use a custom search analyzer that trims the characters of the `name` field
```

**Questions**

1) Is it possible to implement this by somehow configuring how the data are stored/indexed at Elastic Search?

2) If not, is it possible to conditionally change the analyzer of a field at Runtime? (using Java)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use any build in analyzer or any custom analyzer to map your document in elasticsearch. More information on analyzer is [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/analysis-analyzers.html)

The `"term"` query search for exact match. You can find more information about exact match [here (Finding Exact Values)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)

But you can not change a index once it created. If you want to change any index, you have to create a new index and migrate all your data to new index.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about different logic for the analyzer at index and query time.

The solution for your Q1 is to generate two tokens at index time (111a666 -> [111a666, 111666]) but only on token at query time (111a666 -> 111a666 and 111666 -> 111666).

I.m.h.o. your have to generate a new analyzer like
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html which supported `"preserve_original"` like https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html does.
Or you could use two fields (one with original and one without letters) and search over both.